# mutation not commited vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to commit a simple mutation using nuxtServerInit and I can't seem to do it.

My code is as follows:

```
// initial state
export const state = () => ({
  number: 0
});

// getters
export const getters = {};

// mutations
export const mutations = {
  addNumber(state) {
    console.log("addNumber mutation");
    state.number++;
  }
};

// actions
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(context) {
    console.log("nuxtServerInit");
    await context.commit("addNumber");
  },
  addNumber(context) {
    console.log("addNumber action");
    context.commit("addNumber");
  }
};

export default { actions };
```

The `console.log("nuxtServerInit");` is called, but the mutation isn't.

Also I'm getting this error : `[vuex] unknown mutation type: addNumber`

Comment: Are you registering the mutations? Can you provide your store construction code?

Comment: This is done using nuxt, so the store is constructed automatically by nuxt, as far as I understood from the documentation.

Comment: mutations (`commit`s) are not async, they are synchronous. Only actions (`dispatch`) are `async`. In fact, that's the main difference between them. Please provide some visibility over how you register your store module (if it's a module). Are you picking up each individual export from your store (with `import * as someModule from './someModule' `? Because you didn't include `mutations`, `getters` and `state` in the default export, so `import someModule from './someModule'` will only contain the `actions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not exporting anything other than `actions`. You need to export all four items. Change your last line to

```
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

This will export `mutations`, `getters`, and `state` along with your `actions` and your problem will be solved.